# What is the name of optimizing space between laser cut parts?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

When we send some drawings to laser cut operation, they use a proprietary software (usually specific to the laser machine) to duplicate the drawings per request, with the spaces between parts optimized. It's a bit like "panelizing" operation in PCB manufacturing.

What is the name of this optimized assembly operation? (How can we find a proper software to make it by ourselves?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation is called usually [*nesting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_(process)). It is used for almost any type of cutting shapes out of sheets of metal.

One piece of software I used, free (at least at the time) and with very good results (i.e. low slack material) was [deepnest](https://deepnest.io).

There should be other though. A quick search yielded this [page](https://all3dp.com/2/best-laser-cutter-software-for-nesting/) with :

- TruNest
- ProNest 2019
- SVGnest
- SigmaNEST
- MyNesting

Comment: Seeing how Trumpf calls most of their machines "Tru"-something, they were probably pretty bummed to see Autodesk register "TruNest" :D

Comment: Wow deepnest looks incredible +1

Comment: @OpticalResonator so that is to say they were a bit slow off the mark in registering the name. Happened to others before.